# Make %matplotlib qt graph on client machine

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm accessing a remote jupyter notebook server. **I only want to use %matplotlib qt** backend. But %matplotlib qt pops the plot on the server machine, not the client machine. Is there a way to get the plot to come out on the client machine? I am using this "%matplotlib qt" to take input on the graph runtime.